# flex inheritance class share

Tags: apache-flex, class, inheritance, share

```
//Base.as
public class Base
{
    private var _foo:String;

    [Bindable]
    public function set foo(value:String):void
    {
        _foo = value;
    }

    public function get foo():String
    {
        return _foo;
    }

    /*
    Many many setter/getter, methods, events
    */
}

//Control.as
public class MyControl extends Group
{
    public function MyControl()
    {
    }
}

//Window.as
public class MyWindow extends spark.components.Window
{
    public function MyWindow()
    {
    }
}

//Module
public class MyModule extends spark.modules.Module
{
    public function MyModule()
    {
    }
}
```

I want to expose (friendly) Base properties, methods and events on the other classes. Something like this:

```
var window:MyWindow = new MyWindow();
window.foo = 'Hello World!';
var module:MyModule = new MyModule();
module.foo = 'bar';

<namespace:MyControl foo="Hello World!"/>
```

I don't want define all the properties in each class because they are many and the same for all of them.

Ideally would define something like:

```
public class MyControl extends Group, Base
{
    public function MyControl()
    {
    }
}
```

(I know it can't be done.)

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Thanks again!

Maybe this clarify more my need... On business layer I have a variable called processID (and businessID, operationID, localityID, etc.) what be passed to Window from Menu, and Window passes it to Module. On Module Container, I have a CustomComponent what query database using this variable as parameter. This applied for all (almost) Components on Module. These variables are defined as level business layer, then I define a Class to store and manage these variables (and some related methods operating with these variables using business logic), so I can make a standalone class (or library) for every environment to reusing my common components. The idea is... insert a new CustomComponent and set these variables via mxml, like this:

```
<custom:MyCustomComponent id="zzz" processID="{processID}" businessID="{businessID}"/>
```

Module has the business logic for set (o not) any of the variables.

Otherwise, I would have to implement different logic for the CustomComponent (and Module) for read parent's variables and define these variables only in MyWindow (using composite pattern).

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

You can place your classes that require friendly access in the same package as your `Base` class, and define private fields without any access modifier( it is equivalent to `internal` modifier).

Otherwise, you can define your namespace like that:

`namespace my_internal;`

and then define class members like that:

`my_internal var _foo:String;`

after that, those members will be hidden for all code, except for code that contains

`use namespace my_internal;`

You can read more here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9e.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f91

However, using 'friend access' can be an evidence of bad design, so if I were you I'd think twice before defining namespaces.

**Update:**

pseudo-superclass 1:

```
package proxy
{
    public class Simple1
    {
        public var x:int;
        public var y:int;
    }
}
```

pseudo-superclass 2:

```
package proxy
{
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    public class Simple2
    {
        public var name:String = 'noname';
        public function doAlert():void{
            Alert.show(name);
        }

        //not normal method to replace 'this' with proxy
        Simple2.prototype.doCrossClass =  function doCrossClass():void{
            Alert.show(''+(Number(this['x'])+Number(this['y'])));
        }
    }
}
```

Code for testing the result (looks as what you are expecting?):

```
var mega:Mega = new Mega();
mega.x = 100;
mega.y = 200;
mega.name = 'Multiple inheritance';
mega.doAlert();
mega.doCrossClass(); //300
```

And now pseudo-subclass with multiple inheritance:

```
package proxy
{
    import flash.utils.Proxy;
    import flash.utils.flash_proxy;

    public dynamic class Mega extends Proxy
    {
        public function Mega()
        {
            super();
        }

        public var superArray:Array = [new Simple1(), new Simple2()];

        flash_proxy override function getProperty(name:*):*{
            for each(var superClass:Object in superArray){
                if( name in superClass){
                    return superClass[name];
                }
            }
            throw new Error('no such property');
        }

        flash_proxy override function setProperty(name:*, value:*):void{
            for each(var superClass:Object in superArray){
                if( name in superClass){
                    superClass[name] = value;
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw new Error('no such property');
        }

        flash_proxy override function callProperty(name:*, ...args):*{
            for each(var superClass:Object in superArray){
                if( name in superClass){
                    var f:Function = superClass[name] as Function;                  
                    return f.apply(this, args);
                }
            }
            throw new Error('no such function');
        }
    }
}
```

You can also want to use javascript-like class construction(i.e. just using simple Object and assigning properties and functions to it in any combinations you want).

Comment: All classes are in the same library project, so no problem with access. What I want is not define "foo" in each class.

Comment: Then you maybe want to make your classes as subclasses of Proxy, to add all your classes that you want to be your superclasses as members of you new class, and to implement access of members of members. You may also want to use some code generation tool like velocity templates.

Comment: Wow! Interesting... did not know the Proxy pattern... I need study about that... Can you help me with an example please?

Comment: Thanks for example... Yesterday research about proxy and possibly serve me... But, the problem is that my classes has to extend from a Module, Window, Group, etc. I can't put Mega on a Display Object Container (MyGroup on MyWindow).

Comment: About design, I try to do is to extend the properties of common components. For example, I use a BusyIndicator... This I have to use in all components (Window, Module, MyComponent [Group]) and I want showBusy and hideBusy methods. The implementation is the same for all (Window, Module, MyComponent) and I do not want is to implement the same in my 3 components.

Comment: what about assigning standalone functions as methods to prototype of your Window, Module and Component ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your answer from following link -

http://flexinonroids.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/flex-3-dynamically-loading-components-at-runtime/
http://thecomcor.blogspot.in/2007/11/adobe-flex-dynamically-loading-classes.html

Or you can follow below approach -

1) Create an Interface as base
2) Extend your class with interface
3) Load class at runtime with SWFLoader.loaderContext.applicationDomain.getDefinition method

Thanks,

Varun

Comment: If use interfaces, I have to implement the methods in each class which implements and that is precisely what we don't want ... I want something like an inverse of the interface. All classes are in the same library project, so no problem with definition access.